# How do I melt or reshape binned data in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape, melt

I have binned data reflecting the width of rivers across each continent. Below is a sample dataset. I pretty much just want to get the data into the form I have shown.

```
 dat <- read.table(text =    
                      "width continent bin
                      5.32     Africa  10
                      6.38     Africa  10
                      10.80    Asia    20
                      9.45     Africa  10
                      22.66    Africa  30
                      9.45     Asia    10",header = TRUE)
```

How do I melt the above toy dataset to create this dataframe?

```
Bin Count Continent
10  3     Africa
10  1     Asia
20  1     Asia
30  1     Africa
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use either one of the aggregate by group.

The `data.table` option would be to convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dat)`), grouped by 'continent' and 'bin' variables, we get the number of elements per group (.`N`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[,list(Count=.N) ,.(continent,bin)]
#    continent bin Count
#1:    Africa  10     3
#2:      Asia  20     1
#3:    Africa  30     1
#4:      Asia  10     1
```

Or a similar option with `dplyr` by grouping the variables and then use `n()` instead of `.N` to get the count.

```
 library(dplyr)
 dat %>%
      group_by(continent, bin) %>%
      summarise(Count=n())
```

Or we can use `aggregate` from `base R` and using the formula method, we get the `length`.

```
 aggregate(cbind(Count=width)~., dat, FUN=length)
 #   continent bin Count
 #1    Africa  10     3
 #2      Asia  10     1
 #3      Asia  20     1
 #4    Africa  30     1
```

From @Frank's and @David Arenburg's comments, some additional options using `data.table` and `dplyr`.  We convert the dataset to `data.table` (`setDT(dat)`), convert to 'wide' format with `dcast`, then reconvert it back to 'long' using `melt`, and subset the roww (`value>0`)

```
 library(data.table)
 melt(dcast(setDT(dat),continent~bin))[value>0]
```

Using `count` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 count(dat, bin, continent)
```

Comment: For the sake of using `melt` as mentioned in the title: `setDT(melt(dcast(dat,continent~bin)))[value>0]`

Comment: Also `count(dat, bin, continent)`

Answer (score 2):

With `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT bin, continent, COUNT(continent) AS count 
      FROM dat 
      GROUP BY bin, continent")
```

Output:

```
  bin continent count
1  10    Africa     3
2  10      Asia     1
3  20      Asia     1
4  30    Africa     1
```

Comment: You could add `sqldf`

Comment: @akrun thank you again